# How to change android:entries array list in the spinner dynamically in Android

Tags: android, json, listview, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

I am working on a android project where I have 2 Custom spinner

1. State
2. City

i am using below code to to populate the spinner with Custom list view.

**xml code:**

```html
<com.infantstudio.CatholicMithrulu.Spinner.SearchableSpinnerState
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/state"
            app:hintTextState="Select"/>
```

**SearchableListDialogState.class**

```html
package com.infantstudio.CatholicMithrulu.Spinner;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.infantstudio.CatholicMithrulu.R;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchableListDialogState extends DialogFragment implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {

    private static final String ITEMS = "items";

    private ArrayAdapter listAdapter;

    private ListView _listViewItems;

    private SearchableListDialogState.SearchableItem _searchableItem;

    private OnSearchTextChanged _onSearchTextChanged;

    private SearchView _searchView;

    private String _strTitle;

    private String _strPositiveButtonText;

    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener _onClickListener;

    public SearchableListDialogState() {

    }

    public static SearchableListDialogState newInstance(List items) {
        SearchableListDialogState multiSelectExpandableFragment = new
                SearchableListDialogState();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ITEMS, (Serializable) items);

        multiSelectExpandableFragment.setArguments(args);

        return multiSelectExpandableFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams
                .SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Getting the layout inflater to inflate the view in an alert dialog.
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

        // Crash on orientation change #7
        // Change Start
        // Description: As the instance was re initializing to null on rotating the device,
        // getting the instance from the saved instance
        if (null != savedInstanceState) {
            _searchableItem = (SearchableItem) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("item");
        }
        // Change End

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchable_list_dialog, null);
        setData(rootView);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialog.setView(rootView);

        String strPositiveButton = _strPositiveButtonText == null ? "CLOSE" : _strPositiveButtonText;
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(strPositiveButton, _onClickListener);

        String strTitle = _strTitle == null ? "Select Item" : _strTitle;
        alertDialog.setTitle(strTitle);

        final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams
                .SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        return dialog;
    }

    // Crash on orientation change #7
    // Change Start
    // Description: Saving the instance of searchable item instance.
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("item", _searchableItem);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    // Change End

    public void setTitle(String strTitle) {
        _strTitle = strTitle;
    }

    public void setPositiveButton(String strPositiveButtonText) {
        _strPositiveButtonText = strPositiveButtonText;
    }

    public void setPositiveButton(String strPositiveButtonText, DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        _strPositiveButtonText = strPositiveButtonText;
        _onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    public void setOnSearchableItemClickListener(SearchableItem searchableItem) {
        this._searchableItem = searchableItem;
    }

    public void setOnSearchTextChangedListener(OnSearchTextChanged onSearchTextChanged) {
        this._onSearchTextChanged = onSearchTextChanged;
    }

    private void setData(View rootView) {
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context
                .SEARCH_SERVICE);

        _searchView = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search);
        _searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName
                ()));
        _searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        _searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        _searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
        _searchView.clearFocus();
        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context
                .INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(_searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);


        List items = (List) getArguments().getSerializable(ITEMS);

        _listViewItems = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listItems);

        //create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);

        //attach the adapter to the list
        _listViewItems.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        _listViewItems.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        _listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                _searchableItem.onSearchableItemClicked(listAdapter.getItem(position), position);
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        _searchView.clearFocus();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
//        listAdapter.filterData(s);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
//                _listViewItems.clearTextFilter();
            ((ArrayAdapter) _listViewItems.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(null);
        } else {
            ((ArrayAdapter) _listViewItems.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(s);
        }
        if (null != _onSearchTextChanged) {
            _onSearchTextChanged.onSearchTextChanged(s);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public interface SearchableItem<T> extends Serializable {
        void onSearchableItemClicked(T item, int position);
    }

    public interface OnSearchTextChanged {
        void onSearchTextChanged(String strText);
    }
}
```

**SearchableSpinnerState.class**

```html
package com.infantstudio.CatholicMithrulu.Spinner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.infantstudio.CatholicMithrulu.Adddata;
import com.infantstudio.CatholicMithrulu.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;


public class SearchableSpinnerState extends Spinner implements View.OnTouchListener,
        SearchableListDialogState.SearchableItem {

    String selectedItem;
    //this string above will store the value of selected item.

    public static final int NO_ITEM_SELECTED = -1;
    private Context _context;
    private List _items;
    private SearchableListDialogState _searchableListDialog;

    private boolean _isDirty;
    private ArrayAdapter _arrayAdapter;
    private String _strHintText;
    private boolean _isFromInit;

    public SearchableSpinnerState(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this._context = context;
        init();
    }

    public SearchableSpinnerState(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this._context = context;
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SearchableSpinnerState);
        final int N = a.getIndexCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            int attr = a.getIndex(i);
            if (attr == R.styleable.SearchableSpinnerState_hintTextState) {
                _strHintText = a.getString(attr);
            }
        }
        a.recycle();
        init();
    }

    public SearchableSpinnerState(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this._context = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        _items = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("items"+_items);
        _searchableListDialog = SearchableListDialogState.newInstance
                (_items);
        _searchableListDialog.setOnSearchableItemClickListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);

        _arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) getAdapter();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(_strHintText)) {
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(_context, android.R.layout
                    .simple_list_item_1, new String[]{_strHintText});
            _isFromInit = true;
            setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            if (null != _arrayAdapter) {

                // Refresh content #6
                // Change Start
                // Description: The items were only set initially, not reloading the data in the
                // spinner every time it is loaded with items in the adapter.
                _items.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < _arrayAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    _items.add(_arrayAdapter.getItem(i));
                }
                // Change end.

                _searchableListDialog.show(scanForActivity(_context).getFragmentManager(), "TAG");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {

        if (!_isFromInit) {
            _arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) adapter;
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(_strHintText) && !_isDirty) {
                ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(_context, android.R.layout
                        .simple_list_item_1, new String[]{_strHintText});
                super.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            } else {
                super.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        } else {
            _isFromInit = false;
            super.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
    //The method just below is executed  when an item in the searchlist is tapped.This is where we store the value int string called selectedItem.
    @Override
    public void onSearchableItemClicked(Object item, int position) {
        setSelection(_items.indexOf(item));

        if (!_isDirty) {
            _isDirty = true;
            setAdapter(_arrayAdapter);
            setSelection(_items.indexOf(item));
        }
        selectedItem= item.toString().trim();
        Adddata.setValueSt(selectedItem);

//        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"You selected "+selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    private Activity scanForActivity(Context cont) {
        if (cont == null)
            return null;
        else if (cont instanceof Activity)
            return (Activity) cont;
        else if (cont instanceof ContextWrapper)
            return scanForActivity(((ContextWrapper) cont).getBaseContext());

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(_strHintText) && !_isDirty) {
            return NO_ITEM_SELECTED;
        } else {
            return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(_strHintText) && !_isDirty) {
            return null;
        } else {

            return super.getSelectedItem();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine, but I need to change the array at run time . Array is declared in the xml file like this

`android:entries="@array/state"`

How can I modify this array at run time? Any help would be valuable.

--Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create `ArrayList` and insert the entries that you are getting from API or add it.

```
    List < String > list = new ArrayList < > ();
    list.add("Male");
    list.add("Female");
    list.add("Others");
    ArrayAdapter < String > dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerGender.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

**or**

```
    List<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerGender.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    onResposeSucessofAPI(List<String> list){
         this.list = list;
         dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a arrayList of Strings**

```
ArrayList<String> area = new ArrayList<>();
```

**add values in area arrayList**

```
 area.add("value1");
 area.add("value2");
```

**Now set adapter**

```
yourSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context
                            , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, area));
```

Answer (score -1):

Anything declared in `Resources`, cannot be changed at `Runtime`

You must do it by `java code`